# What are the requirements for a book to become a standard edition of the Quran?

Tags: quran

Nowadays, the 1924 Egyptian standard edition has become the standard for modern printings of the Quran ([sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Quran#1924_Cairo_edition) referred on wikipedia).

**Who decides what becomes a standard edition? And how? Based on what requirements? And how is checked if the process and its result are good enough?**

It just sound strange to me that a book that is centuries old has a standard edition of less than 100 years old. That is why I try to understand what the requirements are to make a book standard edition of the Quran, which is, apparently possible many centuries after the Quran become first known.

Comment: There's no such thing as a standard edition of the Qur'an because the Qur'an is the orally transmitted word of Allah it isn't the moshaf. Actually for each Moshafs edition a council of specialists on qira'art, waqf, rasm and other Qur'an related sciences checks the content before giving the go to print and spread it.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Online, a lot of people refer to the 1924 standard edition.  Isn´t this some kind of standard or so? What is it? https://www.google.com/search?q=%221924+Egyptian+standard+edition%22+quran&sxsrf=APq-WBvwR2IwpQvjLH6U5C_GLLhvNoko2Q%3A1649794963792&ei=k99VYsOEMI7BlwSfhbLQAQ&ved=0ahUKEwiDmpOWrY_3AhWO4IUKHZ-CDBoQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%221924+Egyptian+standard+edition%22+quran&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKABOgcIIRAKEKABSgQIQRgBSgQIRhgAUOYCWP4LYJ4QaAFwAHgAgAFtiAGdBJIBAzQuMpgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz

Comment: The only standard was the Moshaf al-Imam which was initiated by 'Uthman ibn 'Affan. The article you are linking says that this is only regarded as a standard for the riwaya of Hafs 'an 'Assim, however Turkish and Pakistani Moshafs differ already from this "standard".